# where i can find tutorial for Epics in redux observale?

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, redux-observable, redux-middleware

I have not found a single tutorial which explains detailed about epics.

```
   onst pingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.filter(action => action.type === 'PING')
    .delay(1000) // Asynchronously wait 1000ms then continue
    .mapTo({ type: 'PONG' });

// later...
dispatch({ type: 'PING' });
```

Comment: Do you use a framework? For angular-redux, you can find an example here: https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/articles/epics.md and for  ngrx (effects) here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/effects/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Our documentation](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html) contains [what we hope is] good documentation, assuming you already have a solid understanding of RxJS. [Have you taken a look?](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/Epics.html)

I noticed you also tagged Angular. You don't have to use [angular-redux](https://github.com/angular-redux/store) to use redux and redux-observable, but if you do they also have [some short docs about using it with redux-observable](https://github.com/angular-redux/store/blob/master/articles/epics.md).

If you have specific questions not answered in the redux-observable docs, feel free to ask them as Stack Overflow questions! :)